# Можно получить доступ к объектам prefab? (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity3d, prefabs

У меня есть prefab:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо обратиться к Terrain("0000") лежащим в этом prefab. Чтоб работать с Terrain("0000") в "Prefab For Editing Mode"(режим работы с префабом). Программно например нарисовать дорогу или разместить деревья в Prefab  в режиме "Prefab For Editing Mode", Когда открываем префаб. То есть мы в коде открываем префаб и сразу выполняем код который отрисовывает дорогу. И в результате при открытии видим изменённый префаб.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GameObject PrefabObj = Resource.Load<GameObject>("path");
```

PrefabObj не объект сцены, а ссылка на твой префаб. Только я не знаю сохранятся ли изменения в префабе, я так обычно цвет материалов меняю глобально.

Comment: Я по другому сделал. (GameObject) GameObject.Instantiate (tempPrefab); .Ваша вариант тоже годный

Comment: Да, но Instantiate это уже не сам prefab, а его экземпляр.

Comment: Это да ....я поменял на этот код GameObject instance = (GameObject) tempPrefab;. И всё заработало как положено. А так у меня плодились префабы

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (prefabEditingBool)
    {
        OpenPrefabForEditing(tempPrefab);
        GameObject instance = (GameObject) tempPrefab;
        Terrain tempTerrain = instance.GetComponentInChildren<Terrain>() as Terrain;
        // Debug.Log(tempTerrain.name);
        List<Terrain> ListPrefabTerrain = new List<Terrain>();
        ListPrefabTerrain.Add(tempTerrain);
        moduleSettings settTerr = new moduleSettings();
        settTerr.DeletTrees(ListPrefabTerrain);
        settTerr.TerrainTexturing(ListPrefabTerrain);
    }
```